# Error en asignación de memoria

Tags: c

Estaba haciendo un programa que trataba de traducir el lenguaje de una supuesta tribu (por ejemplo: si quieren decir "hola que tal", lo que realmente dicen es "laat eeuuq
aalooh", es decir, duplican las vocales). Pues dado el siguiente código:

```
void traducTribu(char *textoOriginal, char *textoTraduc, float *pctVocales, int *longTexto){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    
    InvertirCadena(textoOriginal, textoTraduc);
    *pctVocales = PorcentajeVocales(textoOriginal);
    *longTexto = strlen(textoOriginal);

    int tamFinal = *longTexto;

    while(i < *longTexto){
        if(textoTraduc[i] == 'a' || textoTraduc[i] == 'e' || textoTraduc[i] == 'i' || textoTraduc[i] == 'o' || textoTraduc[i] == 'u'){
            j = i;

            while(j < *longTexto){ 
                textoTraduc[j] = textoTraduc[j+1];
                tamFinal -= 1;                
                j++;
            }
        }

        i++;
    } 

    textoTraduc = (char *) realloc(textoTraduc, tamFinal*sizeof(char));

    if(textoTraduc == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error en asignacion de memoria.");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Se produce un error en la asignación de memoria. En el *main* se reservó memoria de la siguiente manera:

```
textoEsp = (char *) malloc(strlen(texto)*sizeof(char));
```

En el que *texto* es una cadena de carácteres escrita de forma dinámica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al pasar un puntero *`textoTraduc` como argumento en la función traducTribu, el alcance de la función modifica la copia local del puntero que no será modificada fuera de la función.

```
textoTraduc = (char *) realloc(textoTraduc, tamFinal*sizeof(char));
```

corregido el código:

En la función traducTribu se utiliza un puntero a un puntero de carácter.

```
void traducTribu(char *textoOriginal, char **textoTraduc, float *pctVocales, int *longTexto)
```

De esta manera, te aseguras de que el puntero *textoTraduc apunte al nuevo espacio de memoria asignado.

```
*textoTraduc = (char *) realloc(*textoTraduc, tamFinal*sizeof(char));
```

aqui el codigo completo:

```
void traducTribu(char *textoOriginal, char **textoTraduc, float *pctVocales, int *longTexto){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    
    InvertirCadena(textoOriginal, *textoTraduc); //pasar el valor del puntero
    
    *pctVocales = PorcentajeVocales(textoOriginal);
    *longTexto = strlen(textoOriginal);

    int tamFinal = *longTexto;

    while(i < *longTexto){
        if((*textoTraduc)[i] == 'a' || (*textoTraduc)[i] == 'e' || (*textoTraduc)[i] == 'i' || (*textoTraduc)[i] == 'o' || (*textoTraduc)[i] == 'u'){
            j = i;

            while(j < *longTexto){ 
                (*textoTraduc)[j] = (*textoTraduc)[j+1]; 
                tamFinal -= 1;                
                j++;
            }
        }

        i++;
    } 

    *textoTraduc = (char *) realloc(*textoTraduc, tamFinal*sizeof(char));  

    if(*textoTraduc == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error en asignacion de memoria.");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```